# aspectj eclipse plugin to generate pointcuts and advice signature

Tags: eclipse, aspectj

it's quite tedious to manually type a pointcut definition and advice signature for a method; is there any eclipse plugin that does it for you? 
thanks

Comment: look at this: http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/

Answer (score 1):

As [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559070/harry-joy) mentions in the comment, the official Eclipse plugin dealin with AOP is:

**[EclipseAJDT](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/)**

[image]

> The AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT) project provides Eclipse platform based tool support for AOSD with AspectJ.
>   Our goal is to deliver a user experience that is consistent with the Java Development Tools (JDT) when working with AspectJ projects and resources

---

See, for instance, this [recent (September 2010) tutorial](http://www.webreference.com/programming/aspectj/2.html) by [Rob Gravelle](http://www.robgravelle.com/):

[image: new AspectJ dialog]